# How do I render a motion tracked scene?

Tags: rendering, tracking

I just tried my first motion tracking scene in Blender. When I went to "render animation" it came out gray. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?[image]

Here is the node setup if needed.

[image]

Comment: It came out gray but what is it supposed to show? What does your scene look like?

Comment: Video footage with a cube tracked into the scene

Comment: Your render layers seem weird to me. Those two `Render layer` nodes at the bottom shows how your scene renders without the footage composited on it. Is your scene really supposed to look like that?

Comment: I mean, if you only have the default cube and plane in your scene, it should look more like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu2Zj.png

Comment: I know what it is supposed to look like and it doesn't. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: I'm guessing that your objects may be in the wrong collections but it's hard to tell from just pictures. Can you upload your blend file?

Answer (score 0):

On the scene tab, I went to film and enabled transparent.